# Java JButton Unresponsive

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've got a simple program that should accept input from a text field or a button.

However, the button is totally unresponsive.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
public class BoxDiagram extends GraphicsProgram {

private static final int MAX_CHARS = 25;

public void init() {
    addActionListeners();
    nameField = new JTextField(MAX_CHARS);
    nameField.addActionListener(this);
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    add(nameField, SOUTH);
    add(addButton, SOUTH);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == addButton || source == nameField) {
        add(new GLabel("hello", getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2));
    }
}

private JTextField nameField;
private JButton addButton;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is missing: `addButton.addActionListener(this);` You only added it to the name field.